# How do I create a 2D list of lists of ints and setting specific values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I create a matrix which would look like this? I don't want to use numpy.

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [2,0,0,0,0,0],
 [3,0,0,0,0,0],
 [4,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I have tried this, which is wrong:

```
class MinimiumEdits(object):
    def mini(self,str1,str2):

        temp = [[0]*len(str1)]*len(str2)

        for i in range(len(temp[0])):
            temp[0][i] = i
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            temp[i][0] = i


MinimiumEdits().mini("apple","apples")
```

Comment: What have you tried, even if it's wrong ?

Comment: I just edited the post. I have included my code, which is giving me the wrong result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Without importing anything, you can do it like this:

```
def get_list(val, fillvalue=0):
    return [list(range(val+1))] + [[k] + [fillvalue]*val for k in range(1, val)]
# Try with different values like
# get_list(4) or get_list(3)
final = get_list(5)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner lists all reference the same sublist (that's a side-effect of the list multiplication):

```
temp[0] is temp[1]  # True
```

The `is` comparison checks if these are the same object. If you know about pointers this is doing a pointer equality check. Not a value equality (that would be `==` in Python).

That means that all changes are propagated to all "lines". To fix this you could simply change it to:

```
temp = [[0]*len(str1) for _ in range(len(str2))]
```

That should suffice to fix the problem.

Comment: This really helped!! Thanks!

Comment: Almost. Also needs to swap the dimensions.

Comment: @spunkyquagga No problem. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer. :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann What do you mean? Swapping `str1` and `str2`?

Comment: @MSeifert Yes (at least if they really want the shown list of lists).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in a little convoluted way with pure list comprehension:

```
[[x if not y else y if not x else 0 for x in range(6)] for y in range(5)]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```