# Cannot change Numpy array's value?

Tags: python, numpy

I write a simple code list below:

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
xdata = [i + 0.1 for i in data[0]]
print(xdata)
data[0] = xdata
print(data)
```

But the result I get in console i

```
[1.1, 1.1, 1.1]
[[1 1 1]
 [2 3 4]]
```

While I expect it to be

```
[1.1, 1.1, 1.1]
[[1.1 1.1 1.1]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Why I can't change the value in NumPy array this way?

Comment: You need np.insert,

Comment: `data` as created can only hold `int` values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500787/python-numpy-arrays-elements-not-changing-value

Comment: I think your problem is similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500787/python-numpy-arrays-elements-not-changing-value

Comment: `xdata = [i + 0.1 for i in data[0]]` is better written a `xdata = data[0]+0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your array like this

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]], type=np.float64)
```

and it should work. Since you create the array with only integers, its data type becomes np.int64, which means that it can only hold integers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works mostly as expected with one little problem:

This line

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
```

create a numpy-array of type int, and hence this line

```
data[0] = xdata
```

needs to truncate everything behind the decimal point. If you create a float array like this:

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]], dtype=float)
```

everything will work, as expected. However, if you just want to add to the first row 0.1 a nicer complete solution of your code is:

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]], dtype=float)
data[0] += 0.1
```

no list comprehension needed.